# Meaning of "pitch" in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this sentence in a [Stanford blog](https://www.gsb.stanford.edu/insights/one-communication-tool-you-should-add-your-toolkit), titled "One Communication Tool You Should Add to Your Toolkit". What is the meaning of ***pitch*** in this context?

> I often coach clients who need to provide constructive feedback to leverage this structure. For example, you have a colleague who failed to complete his report on time.
>
> What?
> I’ve noticed that your report was not submitted within our agreed upon timeframe.
>
> So what?
> This puts us at a disadvantage for practicing our **pitch** and might jeopardize our client meeting.
>
> Now what?
> I need for you to complete this report by tomorrow morning. Please let me know what I can do to assist you.

Comment: what is 'this' referring to?

Comment: Which of the meanings of 'pitch' which you found in a dictionary seemed to the the kind you might practise for a meeting with a client?

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Point noted. I didn't write the about the research I did. However, michael has now answered it well. Should I remove the question? or Is to possible to move to English Learners's site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the meaning of pitch in this context?

From the very little context given, I would guess it means a *sales pitch*:

> **sales pitch**
>   the statements and promises that someone makes in an attempt to persuade someone else to buy something
>   http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sales-pitch

---

> **pitch**
>   11. *Informal*
>   a. A line of talk designed to persuade: "*[his] pious pitch for ... austerity*" (Boston Globe).
>   b. An advertisement.
>   [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pitch)
>
> A form of words used when trying to persuade someone to buy or accept
>   something:
>   *‘he put over a very strong sales pitch’*
>   https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pitch
>
> 35. (Marketing) *slang* a persuasive sales talk, esp one routinely repeated
>       [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pitch)
> 36. *Informal*. a sales talk, often high-pressured.
>       [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pitch)

Comment: So sales pitch fits here? now

Comment: @pixelr I believe so.